# Symfony 2 with AJAX: Submitting Formatted Request to Controller Method

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a controller method which takes in a JSON Request. The controller returns the data for a submitted form and the updated data is then asynchronously loaded into the page. The form should then be able to be re-submitted any number of times without reloading the page.

The problem I am running into has to do with the JSON data being read by the controller method differently following an initial form submission.

The relevant controller code is:

```
/**
 * Creates a new HoursSpecial entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="hoursspecial_postcreate")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function postCreateAction(Request $request){
    $requestData = $request->request->all();

    $date = $requestData['eventDate']; 

    ...
}
```

And here is the AJAX code:

```
/* Handle submission of special hours form */
$('.specialHours_form').on('submit', function(event){
    var targetForm = $(this);

    event.preventDefault();

    ajaxObject = {
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({"openTime":$("#appbundle_hoursspecial_openTime", this).val(), "closeTime":$("#appbundle_hoursspecial_closeTime", this).val(), "status":$("input[name^='appbundle_hoursspecial']:checked", this).val(), "event":$("#appbundle_hoursspecial_event").val(), "area":$("#appbundle_hoursspecial_area", this).val(), "eventDate":$("#appbundle_hoursspecial_eventDate", this).val()})
    }

    $.ajax(ajaxObject)
        .success(function(data,status,xhr) {
                console.log( status );
                $('#special_hours_container').html(data); //show special hours for chosen week
                $('#dynamic_daterange').html(' Week of ' + $('#special_firstday').html() + ' thru ' + $('#special_lastday').html() + ' ');
                makeTimepicker('.specialHours_form', '#appbundle_hoursspecial_openTime, #appbundle_hoursspecial_closeTime'); //apply timepicker to special hours elements
                $('span.label-success, span.label-danger').remove();
        })
        .fail(function(data,status,xhr) {
                $('span.label-success, span.label-danger').remove();
                $('#appbundle_hoursspecial_submit', targetForm).after('<span class="label label-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>');
                console.log( status );
                console.log("dangah!");
        })
        .always(function(data,status,xhr) {
                console.log( status );
        });
});
```

So if I submit this form the first time around and run a var_dump of $requestData, I get (using sample data):

```
array(6) { ["openTime"]=> string(5) "01:00" ["closeTime"]=> string(5) "11:00" ["status"]=> string(1) "0" ["event"]=> string(1) "1" ["area"]=> string(2) "10" ["eventDate"]=> string(10) "2016-01-04" }
```

**However, if I do it a second time**, the data is placed inside of a second array whose key is the name of the form I am submitting:

```
array(1) { ["appbundle_hoursspecial"]=> array(7) { ["openTime"]=> string(5) "00:30" ["closeTime"]=> string(5) "02:00" ["status"]=> string(1) "0" ["eventDate"]=> string(10) "2016-01-04" ["area"]=> string(2) "10" ["event"]=> string(1) "1" ["submit"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

And obviously I end up with the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: eventDate
```

There has to be a reason for this and I can't figure out what it could be! I know I could just check for the existence of the appbundle_hoursspecial key in my controller, but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Comment: Use `var ajaxObejct`, otherwise you define `ajaxObject` as a global variable. Not sure if it has something to do with your problem, but it may help.

Comment: why post data in json? you could easily use the normal post fields like if you post your form without ajax: $.post('server.php', $('#theForm').serialize())

Comment: @Frankbeen I am using the FOSRestBundle and have it set up to require POST data in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

This likely has to do with the form you are rendering.

```
$('#special_hours_container').html(data);
```

I assume that data is actually the HTML for the form. Likely in your form type you have something like:

```
// HoursSpecialFormType or something

...

public function getName()
{
    return 'appbundle_hoursspecial';
}
```

This would cause all of your new forms that get inserted into the page to be:

```
<input name="appbundle_hoursspecial[openTime]" type=text />
```

Then when your data gets submitted again it will be wrapped in that array.

**To Fix This**

Simply dont provide a form name.

```
public function getName()
{
    return '';
}
```